# isolate stylesheet to div container

Tags: javascript, css

i am looking for a way to prevent conflicts in CSS by isolating a stylesheet to at specific div. The stylesheet is uploaded by a user and to prevent any similar class conflicts I would to know if theres a javascript or CSS way to assign stylesheets to a single div?

Currently, the only thing I can think of, is to get PHP to fetch the css stylesheet, get the content and for each style apply a parent identifier `.container` and then output a new stylesheet, but it would be much nicer if there was a javascript way to do it.

Comment: Apparently you have a solution. Actually, that's probably the only solution (to add a parent identifier).

Comment: You can have a look at the [scoped attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) of style, but it's still badly supported.

Comment: You can use an `iframe` instead of a `div`. Then you can use the stylesheet within that iframe. AFAIK, that's how jsFiddle and similar services work.